# Configure .htaccess with mod_rewrite one level up approach

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

The structure of my project is

/var/www/mysite
------pages
------scripts
------other

In it's corresponding virtual host the configuration is:

```
ServerName mysitename.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/pages/
```

Because of that, when serving the index.php from the pages folder, the resources(scripts/images etc ) are not found, as expected, because the page is trying to load them like so. `http://mysitename.com/scripts/storage.js`.

This of course makes sense.

How would you approach solving this? I am aware that by setting some mod_rewrite rules you can conditionally rewrite urls, is that a way to go about it? **Im mainly interested in seeing what my options are here** rather than getting one solution like, move your .html file up one layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

1. Using `alias` in your Apache server config (of course you need to have control over Apache config). An example of `alias` command:

   ```
   Alias /scripts /var/www/mysite/scripts
   <Directory /var/www/mysite/scripts>
      Options Indexes
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
2. Create a symbolic link inside `pages/` directory. For example on `*nix` systems use this command to create symlinks:

   ```
   cd pages
   ln -s ../scripts .
   ln -s ../other .
   ```

Comment: How would method 1. work? I didnt understand it, sorry. p.s: i have complete control and sudo privileges

Comment: I have added an example of `alias`  command. It goes in `vhost.conf` or `httpd.conf` file

Comment: oh i didnt think i could add more directories. this makes perfect sense, thank you

Comment: sorry to impose, another question. Solution 1. is something that can only be done on the apache.conf and not per virtual host, correct?

Comment: It can be done per `VirtualHost`. In fact I am using it inside `VirtualHost` on my Apache.

Comment: And finally, for completion, it could also be done using mod_rewrite rules, correct?

Comment: No `mod_rewrite` rules cannot be used since path `/var/www/mysite/scripts` exists outside your `DocumentRoot` path